# Обособление вводного слова "может"

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, запятые, невыделение-вводных

**Если ты уже проработал какое-то время и что-то делал, то результаты, может(,) не такие грандиозные, но всегда есть.**

Здесь вводное слово "может" вроде как стоит в начале обособленного оборота, но проблема в том, что союз "но", неразрывно связанный с оборотом, делает невозможным изъятие этого оборота. Однако если рассмотреть "не такие грандиозные" как сказуемое, то вводное слово "может" при наличии после неё запятой можно изъять без проблем. Поэтому я склоняюсь к тому, что запятая нужна. Как думаете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Если ты уже проработал какое-то время и что-то делал, то результаты, может не такие грандиозные, но всегда есть.**

Сравнить:

Если ты уже проработал какое-то время и что-то делал, то результаты, **хотя и не такие грандиозные,** но всегда есть.

Вводное слово "может" выполняет роль союза **в этой конструкции с союзом НО** (она рассматривается как единое целое), поэтому обособлять "может" нежелательно, да и лишние запятые будут затруднять прочтение текста.

Пример:

Или можно сконструировать новые изделия, **может не такие хорошие по характеристикам, но допускающие** их принятие на вооружение без испытаний? [А. Д. Сахаров. Воспоминания (1983-1989)]